# Force browser to trig change event

Tags: javascript, html, input, onchange

I guess this is not possible, but maybe someone has a trick to do what I need.

On an `input`, `change` event is trigged when bluring the field and if, and only if, the value has changed since last ... "time". I do not know how the browser store the *previous changed value* to compare with the current one and trig `change` event when bluring.

I need to manually reset (if possible) this *previous changed value* during the user is typing, to force the browser naturally trig the `change` event when bluring, even if the current value equals the previous one.

Everything is describe in this jsFiddle (with instructions and **constraints** )

### [Demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/cs3fyxj4/)

Many thanks

Comment: You mean `$(document).on('input change paste blur', '.sekector', function(){$('#inputField').trigger('change')})`

Comment: No. I dont want to trig the change event manually (and less on input or paste events). I want to make the  event triggered naturally by the browser to respect natural events order and priority. That is why I try to modify the _previous_ value manually during the input is typed ... and let the browser do its job.

Comment: But when you trigger `change` event, all events, related to `change` will be triggered too.

Comment: yes, thx. But I dont want to trig the change event each time the value has changed. And if I do something within a blur or focusout events, the natural order and priorities will not be respected. (usually change is trigged before the focusout. Here, it would be triggered to late). You see what I mean ?